# error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, Object>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm-install, npm-start

How can I solve this problem?

```
Angular CLI: 14.0.2
Node: 16.13.0
rxjs: 7.5.5
typescript: 4.7.4
```

My imports :

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { first, catchError, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Error on *first()*,

```
    login(
    email: Pick<User, "email">,
    password: Pick<User, "password">
  ): Observable<{
    token: string;
    userId: Pick<User, "id">;
  }> {
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.url}/login`, { email, password }, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        first(),
        tap((tokenObject: { token: string; userId: Pick<User, "id"> }) => {
          this.userId = tokenObject.userId;
          localStorage.setItem("token", tokenObject.token);
          this.isUserLoggedIn$.next(true);
          this.router.navigate(["/"]);
        }),
        catchError(
          this.errorHandlerService.handlerError<{
            token: string;
            userId: Pick<User, "id">;
          }>("login")
        )
      );
  }
```

Comment: What's the full error message? The title is truncated so it doesn't contain the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the return type of `post` so that it matches the return type of the function.

```js
return this.http.post<{
    token: string;
    userId: Pick<User, "id">;
  }>( ... )
  .pipe( ... )
```

The return types within the pipe can be inferred by the compiler, but there is no way to tell the return type of `post` without you explicitly stating it.

I'd suggest you make a type so the code isn't so verbose

```js
type TokenAndId = {
    token: string;
    userId: Pick<User, "id">;
  }
```

```js
  login(
    email: Pick<User, 'email'>,
    password: Pick<User, 'password'>
  ): Observable<TokenAndId> {
    return this.http
      .post<TokenAndId>(
        `${this.url}/login`,
        { email, password },
        this.httpOptions
      )
      .pipe(
        first(),
        tap((tokenObject: TokenAndId) => {
          this.userId = tokenObject.userId;
          localStorage.setItem('token', tokenObject.token);
          this.isUserLoggedIn$.next(true);
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }),
        catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handlerError<TokenAndId>('login'))
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [this](https://www.angularfix.com/2022/01/angular-argument-of-type-void-is-not.html) guide, you specified the returned function type as

```
Observable<{
    token: string;
    userId: Pick<User, "id">;
  }>
```

You need to specify the expected returned value type in `post<T>` and  `first<T>` operators as well.